# Python code works as module but not as class

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-canvas

I tried to find out why, but maybe don't know the right questions. I have a project where I'm trying to create a dashboard for my car. The problem is that when I try to make a canvas object from another class appear my GUI starts but does not show anything. If I start the GUI without asking for the canvas to appear the GUI works and shows the screen. I'm new to Python. My version is 3.5

My Main program:

```
from tkinter import*
from helperThingys import Helpers

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x480")

bgLeft = Frame(root, bg="black", width=200, height=480)
bgLeft.pack_configure(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)
bgMiddle = Frame(root, bg="black", width=400, height=480)
bgMiddle.pack_configure(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)
bgRight = Frame(root, bg="black", width=200, height=480)
bgRight.pack_configure(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)

# These are really gif images read to labels to be able to grid them
# now just plain text labels for convenience. 
label_4hi = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="green")
label_4lo = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="green")
label_lock = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="green")
label_batt = Label(bgMiddle, text="ok", bg="red")
label_fuelF = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="orange")
label_glow = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="yellow")
label_hb = Label(bgMiddle, text="ok", bg="blue")
label_indL = Label(bgMiddle, text="ok", bg="green")
label_indR = Label(bgMiddle, text="ok", bg="green")
label_lowFuel = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="red")
label_lowOil = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="red")
label_park = Label(bgMiddle, text="ok", bg="red")
label_pwrS = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="red")
label_rFog = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="orange")
label_temp = Label(bgLeft, text="ok", bg="red")
label_gauge = Label(bgMiddle, text="ok", bg="red")

# Middle frame
bgMiddle.rowconfigure(0, minsize=46, weight=1)
bgMiddle.rowconfigure(1, minsize=217, weight=5)
bgMiddle.rowconfigure(2, minsize=217, weight=5)
bgMiddle.columnconfigure(0, minsize=80)
bgMiddle.columnconfigure(1, minsize=80)
bgMiddle.columnconfigure(2, minsize=80)
bgMiddle.columnconfigure(3, minsize=80)
bgMiddle.columnconfigure(4, minsize=80)

label_indL.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+N+W)
label_hb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_park.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_batt.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_indR.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=E+N+S+W)

# Left frame
bgLeft.rowconfigure(0, minsize=46, weight=1)
bgLeft.rowconfigure(1, minsize=46, weight=1)
bgLeft.rowconfigure(2, minsize=46, weight=1)
bgLeft.rowconfigure(3, minsize=46, weight=1)
bgLeft.rowconfigure(4, minsize=46, weight=1)
bgLeft.columnconfigure(0, minsize=100)
bgLeft.columnconfigure(1, minsize=100)

label_4hi.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_4lo.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_lock.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_pwrS.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_rFog.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_lowFuel.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_lowOil.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_temp.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_fuelF.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E+N+S+W)
label_glow.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E+N+S+W)

# Middle frame
speedo = helpers.Gauge()
speedo.makeGauge(bgMiddle, 150, "speed")
speedo.grid(row=1, columnspan=5, sticky=E+N+S+W)
#label_gauge.grid(row=1, columnspan=5, sticky=E+N+S+W)

# Right Frame

#oilPres = Gauge(bgRight, 150, "oilPres")

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the 'helpers.py' from helperThingys package.

```
from tkinter import Canvas

class Gauge(Canvas):

    def __init__(self):
        Canvas.__init__(self)
        pass

    def makeGauge(self, window, value, gaugeType):
        if gaugeType == "speed":
            baseCanvas = Canvas(window, bg="black", width=400, height=217,
                                highlightthickness=0)
            baseCanvas.create_arc([10, 5, 390, 395], start=0, extent=180,
                                  fill="white")
            return baseCanvas
```

I'm using the canvases as the background for the gauges. The strange thing was that this 'helpers.py' worked and created the canvases to my GUI when it was not a class but a module:

```
def makeGauge(self, window, value, gaugeType):
    if gaugeType == "speed":
        baseCanvas = Canvas(window, bg="black", width=400, height=217,
                                highlightthickness=0)
        baseCanvas.create_arc([10, 5, 390, 395], start=0, extent=180,
                                  fill="white")
        return baseCanvas
```

... and so on (the module was then in the same package as the GUI). That's why I know that the canvases work with the GUI. What am I doing wrong when using them in a class?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Is all of this code really necessary to duplicate the problem? Please remove anything that's not strictly related to the problem. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for the comment, wasn't sure how much code was really needed because of how it would affect the item sizes in the GUI. Edited some off that wasn't necessary. (I Think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `Gauge` both is a subclass of `Canvas` *and* creates one or more other canvases (that are, oddly, a child of some other window).

When you call `makeGauge`, this creates the second canvas, and returns it. However, you don't save a reference and you never call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on this second canvas so it never shows up.

I don't know what you're intending to do with the two canvases, but I'm guessing you really only want one. I suggest making the class like this, where you pass all arguments in at the time you create the canvas, so that you can create the gauge in a single step:

```
class Gauge(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, value, gaugeType):
        Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.makeGauge(value, gaugeType)

    def makeGauge(self, value, gaugeType):
        if gaugeType == "speed":
            self.configure(bg="black", width=400, height=217,
                           highlightthickness=0)
            self.create_arc([10, 5, 390, 395], start=0, extent=180,
                            fill="white")

        elif gaugeType == "rpm":
            ...

speedo = Gauge(bgMiddle, 150, "speed")
speedo.grid(...)
```

If you want to keep both canvases, or you decide to make `Gauge` inherit from something else, you  need to save the reference that is returned by `makeGauge`, and then add it to the display:

```
gauge = speedo.makeGauge(bgMiddle, 150, "speed")
gauge.grid(row=1, columnspan=5, sticky=E+N+S+W)
```

Comment: @TonninSeteli: yes, that's another solution. Though, you end up with twice as many canvas objects than you need.

Comment: I think my problem was that I didn't save the reference. Couldn't get it to work with the code above but got it working like when calling like this: speedo = Helpers.Gauge().makeGauge(bgMiddle, 150, "speed")

Comment: But is the baseCanvas object "alive" still after returning it and going away from the Helpers.py?

Comment: @TonninSeteli: it still exists as an object and takes up a tiny amount of memory.

Comment: How do you call the `makeGauge` function in case of the _one Canvas object_ in the main program? Should it then work with just: `speedo.makeGauge(*args)`? Trying to learn to make "clean" code with no trash objects. A padawan thanks the Master.